# Как сделать вот такие числа? чёрножёлтые

Tags: css3, html5

Как сделать такие чёрножёлтые числа как на картинке?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-shadow` - вот, что вам нужно.

Вот пример, значения уже подбирайте сами.

```css
span
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #EAC61E;
}
```

```html
<span>01</span>
```